# Why is wp action hook not working for function that removes shortcode based on specific url string

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm trying to understand why in my functions.php file in my child theme I'm able to successfully suppress a shortcode based on whether a specific string is in the url.

However, I can't do the same thing the "proper way" by using a function and action hook.

Example: So I'm able to get expected behavior if in my functions.php, I have...

```
snip

if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/?s=") !== false )
    remove_shortcode('uwr-button');

snip
```

But I'm unsuccessful if I do the following in my functions.php file:

```
snip

function remove_shortcode_exec_on_query(){

    // condition to disable uwr-button shortcode
    if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/?s=") !== false )
            remove_shortcode('uwr-button');

}
add_action('wp','remove_shortcode_exec_on_query'); 

snip
```

You can see the buggy behavior if I comment out the top snippet and uncomment out the bottom snippet, which is shown in this link:
https://s1.temporary-access.com/~allacros/devel/?s=tahiti